# Can an integrated GPU act as dedictaed GPU at the same time?

Tags: laptop, memory, graphics-card, gpu

I have a rather confusing situation concerning the GPUs in my 2 laptops.

The first laptop (Dell) has Intel Iris Xe GPU, and from task manager I can tell it is shared with system RAM and the total GPU memory is 3.9GB:

[image]

The second laptop (Asus) is AMD based with a Ryzen 3 Vega GPU, but it shows that there is 2.0GB "dedicated memory", and IIRC it is integrated, but when I look at the total GPU memory it adds up to 5.0 GB (instead of about 3.0 GB since it shares with system RAM just like the former):

[image]

Where is extra memory coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to check your BIOS for how the integrated graphics are set up. Sometimes it's an explicit pre-allocation and sometimes it's automatic or real-time.

In the Intel screenshot I see you have access to the full 8 GB of RAM which tells me that the iGPU is allowed to consume up to 4 GB of RAM but if your system is using 6 GB already then the iGPU will have to fight for anything above 2 GB.

The Ryzen 3 Vega iGPU seems to have 2 GB "dedicated"; I would call it pre-allocated. This means that the system cannot use more than 6 GB out of the presumably 8 GB (installed). However if Vega exceeds, highly unlikely, the 2 GB pre-allocation then it can tap into an additional 3 GB.

Answer (score 0):

The shared memory is system memory which is shared between your CPU and your GPU.
It seems like your intel card has no internal memory and only used shared memory.

Your AMD GPU uses both its dedicated, internal, memory as well as shared memory. They simply add up:

`2GB dedicated GPU memory + 3GB shared GPU memory = 5GB total GPU memory`

Comment: Thanks wanted to get confirmation if that GPU is using its own dedicated memory and not shared, but on specs they say its integrated.